# What exactly is the mercy seat?

Tags: exodus

English Standard Version Exodus 25:20

> The cherubim shall spread out their wings above, overshadowing the mercy seat with their wings, their faces one to another; toward the mercy seat shall the faces of the cherubim be.

What is the significance of the mercy seat?

Comment: This is a very large subject, sir. And very much misunderstood. The word is not 'mercy' it is _ilios_ (not _helios_) and it is not a 'seat'. '_Hilasterion_ contains no etymology like to either _hedra_ (seat) or _thronos_ (throne). The Hebrew is _kapporeth_ and there again there is confusion regarding what _kaphar_ means (it does not mean 'atone'). I could write an entire book on this. (In fact, I already did.) [Link](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxiZWxtb250cHVibGljYXRpb25zfGd4OjNlYWMyNDEyNWFiY2E4MzE) Good Question +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "mercy seat" does not ever occur in the original language of the Bible, Hebrew nor Greek.  It is an interpretive translation of some versions, eg, ESV, NASB, NKJV, KJV, CSB, etc.

The operative word is כַּפֹּ֫רֶת (kapporeth) (Ex 25:17-22, 26:34, 30:6, 31:7, 37:-9, 39:35, 40:20, Lev 16:2, 13-15, Num 7:89, 1 Chron 28:11).

BDB defines the meaning as:

> כַּמֹּרֶת noun propitiatory, late technical word from כּפר cover over
> sin: the older explanation cover, lid has no justification in usage;
> ᵐ5 ιλαστήριον; only P: Exodus 25:17,18,19,20 (twice in verse); Exodus
> 25:21,22; Exodus 26:34; Exodus 30:6; Exodus 31:7; Exodus 35:12; Exodus
> 37:6,7,8,9 (twice in verse); Exodus 39:35; Exodus 40:20; Leviticus
> 16:2 (twice in verse); Leviticus 16:13,14 (twice in verse); Leviticus
> 16:15 (twice in verse); Numbers 7:89, and 1 Chronicles 28:11; it was a
> slab of gold 22-Jancubits x 1 2-Jancubits placed on top of the ark of
> the testimony. On it, and a part of it, were two golden cherubim
> facing each other, whose outstretched wings came together above and
> constituted the throne of Yahweh. When the high priest entered the
> Holy of Holies on the day of atonement it was necessary that this
> highest place of atonement should be enveloped in a cloud of incense.
> The blood of the sin-offering of the atonement was then sprinkled on
> the face of and seven times before it. The temple proper, as
> distinguished from porch etc., was called ׳בֵּית הַכּ 1 Chronicles
> 28:11.

The NY Greek word is ἱλαστήριον (hilasterion) with a very similar meaning, Heb 9:5, but also used more generally ("Propitiation") as per Rom 3:25.

It was essentially the covering or top of the "Ark or the Covenant" (Num 10:33, 14:44, Deut 10:8, 31:9, 25, 26, Josh 3:3, 6, 8, 11, 14, 17, 4:7, 9, 18, 6:6, 8:33, etc) or, “Ark of the Testimony” (Ex 25:22, 26:33, 34, 30:6, 26, 31:7, 39:35, 40:3, 5, 21, Lev 16:13, Num 4:5, 7:89, Josh 4:16, etc) is described thus precisely because it contained the stone tablets inscribed by the finger of God (Ex 31:18, Deut 9:10) with the Israelite Covenant of the 10 Commandments.  1 Kings 8:9, 2 Chron 5:10.

This covering is deeply significant - it was a solid gold covering with two angels of solid gold facing each other looking toward the cover.  It is more helpfully translated "atonement cover" (or similar) by NIV, NLT, NET, BST, DRB.

Once per year, the High priest sprinkled blood on the atonement cover as part of the Great Day of Atonement, Lev 16.  Thus, this atonement cover was inextricably linked with the day of atonement when propitiation or atonement was made for the everyone in the nation.

The name "mercy seat" (originally a "protestant" translation) came into use because of the Jewish tradition (not explicit in the Bible) that the "Shekinah Glory", or visible presence of God, "sat" above this cover.

Answer (score 1):

"Ha-Kapporet" (הַכַּפֹּֽרֶת) : the-Atonement (כַּפֵּר) Sign (ת) is a gold covering over ha-Aron (הָֽאָרֹ֑ן) "the Ark" containing the Torah. This gold mediation platform measures 2.5-cubits long by 1.5-cubits wide [Exodus 25:17].

"The Mercy Seat" or the-Atonement Sign, "Ha-Kapporet" (הַכַּפֹּֽרֶת) is armed with 2 golden figurines called "Keruvim" (כְּרֻבִ֖ים) symbolizing 2 heavenly witnesses of God's Covenant with Yisrael [Exodus 25:18-20].

> Shemot 25:17 [MT] :
> "And you shall make an ark cover of pure gold, two and a half cubits its length and a cubit and a half its width." (וְעָשִׂ֥יתָ כַפֹּ֖רֶת זָהָ֣ב טָה֑וֹר אַמָּתַ֤יִם וָחֵ֨צִי֙ אָרְכָּ֔הּ וְאַמָּ֥ה וָחֵ֖צִי רָחְבָּֽהּ)

> Shemot 25:18 [MT] :
> "And you shall make two golden Keruvim; you shall make them of hammered work, from the two ends of the ark cover." (וְעָשִׂ֛יתָ שְׁנַ֥יִם כְּרֻבִ֖ים זָהָ֑ב מִקְשָׁה֙ תַּֽעֲשֶׂ֣ה אֹתָ֔ם מִשְּׁנֵ֖י קְצ֥וֹת הַכַּפֹּֽרֶת)

> Shemot 25:19 [MT] : 
> "And make one Keruv from the one end and the other Keruv from the other end; from the ark cover you shall make the Keruvim on its two ends." (וַֽ֠עֲשֵׂ֠ה כְּר֨וּב אֶחָ֤ד מִקָּצָה֙ מִזֶּ֔ה וּכְרוּב־אֶחָ֥ד מִקָּצָ֖ה מִזֶּ֑ה מִן־הַכַּפֹּ֛רֶת תַּֽעֲשׂ֥וּ אֶת־הַכְּרֻבִ֖ים עַל־שְׁנֵ֥י קְצוֹתָֽיו)

> Shemot 25:20 [MT] : 
> "The Keruvim shall have their wings spread upwards, shielding the ark cover with their wings, with their faces toward one another; [turned] toward the ark cover shall be the faces of the Keruvim." (וְהָי֣וּ הַכְּרֻבִים֩ פֹּֽרְשֵׂ֨י כְנָפַ֜יִם לְמַ֗עְלָה סֹֽכְכִ֤ים בְּכַנְפֵיהֶם֙ עַל־הַכַּפֹּ֔רֶת וּפְנֵיהֶ֖ם אִ֣ישׁ אֶל־אָחִ֑יו אֶ֨ל־הַכַּפֹּ֔רֶת יִֽהְי֖וּ פְּנֵ֥י הַכְּרֻבִֽים)

Comment: +1 for describing the mercy seat as being "armed with 2 golden figurines", which is absolutely fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

The significance of the Mercy seat can be seen in what it ‘covered’. The Ark was ‘housed’ in the inner section of the Tabernacle, the Holy of Holies. This is where God met/interacted with the High Priest. It’s construction is outlined in the book of Exodus. (See chapter 37).

The items inside the Ark, a pot of Manna, Aaron’s rod, and the 10 commandments, are symbolic of mans rebellion, specifically the rebellion of the children of Israel - and this needed ‘mercy’. (‘kaphar’). These needed God”s Mercy (not getting what you deserve.)
In this way, the Mercy seat ‘covered’ their rebellion.

The Cherebum are heavenly beings created to protect, enforce, guard, ‘cover’ Gods righteousness, and they would not allow any unrighteousness to approach, or be seen by God. The Mercy seat - representing Gods Mercy, shielded’ the rebelliousness of the children of Israel from these Cherebum.

Hence the reason for sprinkling blood on the Mercy seat whenever the High Priest entered the Holy of Holies, during Yom Kippur. This blood ‘covered’ the sin, (from the ‘eyes’ of the Cherebum.)

(Yom Kippur, ‘Kaphar’ -  ‘to cover/protect’. Same principle as the ‘pitch’ applied to the outside/inside of Noah’s Ark, pitch also from the same Hebrew word. A ‘protection’ from judgement.)

Much to this, but ‘digging’ into this will prove very interesting, for example, making ‘sense’ of the goat that was released during Yom Kippur.